# Select relational values (many to many) while creating new Account

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object call location and I would like to add an association (many to many) with Account object. 
One account can have more than one locations. 
I did create a junction object and manage to create many to many relations between account and sales area.

But my question is how can I select the location(s) while creating the new account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you you are using SF classic, then create VF page and override standard view page with your custom VF page. In this page develop controller that  will allow to select location and will create junction object with ids of `Account` and `Location`

if you are using lightning experience, then you can develop lightning component and simply add it to `Account` record page. Server-side controller should have the same functionality as for classic-style version.